# PostgreSQL Function Return from Second Query if First Query is Empty

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I have a PostgreSQL 11x environment in Windows. I am trying to figure out syntax for a Function which returns results of a query. The first query in the code below works much better most of the time but if it fails to return something then I'd like to use the second query's return--which is much slower but at least has some data being returned. Here is my Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.myfunction()
RETURNS TABLE(start_vid bigint, end_vid bigint, agg_cost double precision)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE 
--declarations
BEGIN   
 RETURN QUERY
 SELECT  * FROM pgr_dijkstraCost(
        'SELECT gid as id, * FROM ways  as r, 
        (SELECT ST_Expand(ST_Extent(the_geom), ' || box_size || ') as box  FROM ways as edge_table    
        WHERE edge_table.source = ' || VT1 || ' OR edge_table.target = ' || VT2 || ') as box
        WHERE r.the_geom && box.box',
        VT1, VT2, arg_directed_flag::boolean
RETURN QUERY
    SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstraCost( 'SELECT gid as id, * FROM ways', VT1, VT2, 
   arg_directed_flag::boolean); 
END
$function$
```

Note: I want to execute the second SELECT only if the first Select doesn't return anything. Can't find any code for PostgreSQL to modify my function and fairly new to PostgreSQL environment.

Thank you!

Comment: It *looks like* you could restructure your query into a LEFT JOIN ...

Comment: Thank you. I have accepted an Answer otherwise would give it a try.

Comment: You really should give it a try, your query is barely readable, IMHO. It could cost you 15 minutes now, but it could save hours of maintenance work. Also: try to get rid of the string concatenation; it is a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: But won't LEFT JOIN make the second SELECT query to execute? That's what I am trying to desperate avoid because the second select is very slow and is only a fall back plan. Thank you.

Comment: Basically, I cannot read (and understand) your query. Why do you need the scalar subquery?  Is it even correlated? Why do you use all these `SELECT *`s ? And the second query is *slow* because it retrieves the complete ways table, which probably is quite large.

Comment: Both queries return these otherwise the Function call would fail: 'SELECT gid as id, * FROM ways'. As you can see, the first query attempts to select only a part of the pgRouting graph based on the incoming incoordinates; this dramatically increases the speed but if there are no returns then the second query is executed which tries to find the entire loaded data's graph. This is an adoption of a GIS Stack Exchange solution for 'pgRouting too slow for larger data'. I am making progress but not 100% there. Thank you.

Comment: this answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68684745/how-to-execute-a-2nd-query-if-the-first-one-returns-nothing#answer-68686990

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`FOUND`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) variable, which is `true` if the previous query returned at least one row

```sql
IF (FOUND = FALSE) THEN
 RETURN QUERY
    SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstraCost( 'SELECT gid as id, * FROM ways', VT1, VT2, 
   arg_directed_flag::boolean); 
END IF;
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me see if I can figure this out in my code...

Comment: Wow! All I had to do was to wrap my second RETURN QUERY surrounded by the IF statement you sent me and voila!! Thank you so much!!